# State changed in parent component, child components do not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I am building a whack-a-mole app and I have a component which:

- renders each `row`
- generates a random number that is an `index` to what hole the mole pops out of

This generates 5 holes per row, and the hole with the randomly generated index gets a boolean to mark if it will have a mole.

When the `mole` is clicked;

- it calls a function to change state of the `Row` component by assigning a new random number.
- `console.log()` shows that it does regenerate a random number, and the variable that is mapped with each `Hole` component also receives the new, updated `Hole` components with a new index to have a `mole`.

**Challenge**
The initial rendering works good. Moles are placed at random holes, and the mole disappears when clicked.

However, no `mole` appears at the new index, nor do the `hole` components re-render, as none of that components `console.log()`s show up.

Even though the parents state is changed, and the new props for the set of `holes` are re-rendered, how come the Hole components are never actually run?

The method to change the hole number is in the `Row` component, and the number and variable holding the new components is there as well.

So I imagine that the problem may lie somewhere in the Hole component.

```js
class Rows extends Component{
    
    state = { holeNum: null  };

    componentWillMount() {
       this.changeSpot();
    };

    changeSpot = () => {
       // console.log(this.state.holeNum);
       let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(5));
       this.setState({ holeNum: random });
       // console.log("Spot changed ", this.state.holeNum, random)
    }

    render() {        
       // console.log("ROW ", this.props.id)
       let holes = [0,1,2,3,4];
       // console.log(this.state.holeNum)
       let row = holes.map(idx => {
          // if holeNum is equal to index has mole is true
          // console.log("rerendering")
          let moleRender = false;
          if(this.state.holeNum === idx){
              moleRender = true;
              // console.log(idx, moleRender, this.state.holeNum)            
          };
            
          return (
            <Hole
               changeSpot={this.changeSpot}
               updateScore={this.props.updateScore}
               hasMole={moleRender}
            />
          );
       });

       // console.log(row)

       return (
          <div className="Row">
             {row}
          </div>
       );
    };
};
```

And here is the `Hole` component

```js
class Hole extends Component{
    
    state = { hasMole: false };

    componentWillMount(){
       // console.log("Comp will mount Hole")
       if(this.props.hasMole===true){
          // console.log(this.props.hasMole)
          this.setState({hasMole:true});
       };
    };

    moleClickedHandler = () => {
       this.setState({ hasMole:false });
       // this.props.updateScore()
       this.props.changeSpot();
    };
    
    render() {
       let mole = null;
       if(this.state.hasMole === true){
           // console.log(this.state.hasMole)
           mole = <Mole clicked={this.moleClickedHandler} />;
       };

       return (
           <div className="Hole">
              {mole}
           </div>
       );
    };
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any console warnings about a missing `key` prop?  If you're using `.map` to generate components I imagine React will want that to track them-- it could be related to the issue you're seeing...

Comment: I added the keys and played around with things, and I realized the issue is with the lifecycle of the child component <Hole />. The 'hasMole' property of setState only became true when the Hole mounted. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting a warning in console of Developer tool relate to missing "key" prop
You can learn more why key is necessary here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

You can solve this issue by adding key

```
         <Hole
            key={ix}
            changeSpot={this.changeSpot}
            updateScore={this.props.updateScore}
            hasMole={moleRender}/>
```